# php words spinner issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a spinner function to spin a string and replace a words on it from mysql table I used this function:

```
function mradef($text)
{
    global $db;
    $text = trim($text);
    $word = explode(" ", $text);
    $finalword='';
    foreach($word as $words) {
        $q = $db->query("select simple_id,name,synonym from simple where name='$words'");
        while($t = $db->fetch($q)){
            $finalword .= str_replace($words, 
                                  '<b>' . $t['synonym'] . '( ' . $words . ' )</b>', 
                                  ' ' . $text . ' ');

            return $finalword;
        }
    }
}

$amer = 'hello my name is Amer and I am a php programmer';
echo mradef($amer);
```

And my table ( simple ) contain thees rows

```
name       | synonym 
--------------
hello      | hi
programmer | web programmer
```

But the code is not working. All what you need to do is make that code change any word inside the string to the (synonym) from the database.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
return $finalword;
```

Should be outside of `foreach` loop, that's your error.

Also, all words that are not found in database, are not appended to the `$finalword`. To add them, add a condition (if there are no any mysql results) and append the word without changes.